In my nextjs app useEffect hook run on every time i visit same page
I have NextJS app with app router and inside I have different routes like home, dashboard, About etc. When I visit dasboard for the first time, useEffect run after that i visit other routes and then i visit dashboard next time then also run useEffect. i confirm by console.log("renderd useeffect");
function Dasboard(): React.ReactElement {
  const { data: Session } = useSession()
  const [acceptMessageStatus, setAcceptMessageStatus] = useState(false)
  // const [isAcceptingMessage, setIsAcceptingMessage] = useState(false)
  const user = userStore((state) => state.user);
  const setUser = userStore(state => state.setUser)
  const [feedbackUrl, setFeedbackUrl] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user && Session?.user) {
      console.log("user set : ",Session.user);
      setUser(Session.user)
      console.log("session : ",Session);
    }
  }, [Session, setUser, user])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("render useeffect");
    if(user){
      (async () => {
        try {
          const res = await axios.get('api/accept-messages')
          if (res.data) {
            console.log("accept message : ", res);
            // setIsAcceptingMessage(res.data.isAcceptingMessage)
            setUser({ ...user, isAcceptingMessage: res.data.isAcceptingMessage })
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      })();
    }
    
  }, [setUser,user]);


 

  useEffect(() => {
    setFeedbackUrl(`${location.origin}/u/${user?.username}`);
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <div className=' w-full flex flex-col px-1 xl:px-56 lg:px-40 md:px-12 max-md:px-24 max-sm:px-2 pt-14 '>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Dasboard

I want a solution that solves the problem of unnecessary useEffect call on every re-visit.
Thank you 

Visiting some other page unmounts your Dashboard component and re-visiting Dashboard mounts your component. Your useEffect runs every time when the component mounts or one of the variables in your dependency array changes. Check out how useEffect works: https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect

Could you share the way you change page? Are you using next router?

Can you please check this question link

As someone said, since your Dashboard component gets unmounted when visiting another page, re-visiting will trigger the useEffect "again". Your solution would be to move the useEffect's logic up the component tree to make sure that the it does not get unmounted on page changes (maybe on the layout level?). That way you can change pages while keeping the component with the useEffect still mounted across page changes.
